# Support multiple languages in symfony 2

Tags: database, symfony, multiple-languages

I'm looking for a tutorial about how to design the database schema to support multiple languages in symfony 2 and found [this](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_0/en/13-I18n-and-L10n). Unfortunately it's for symfony 1.3 and it's deprecated. I'm wondering how to support multiple languages in symfony 2? (Especially how to design the database schema.) Thanks.

Comment: check out this: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: why don't you use the [translation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)? it work very well

Comment: Yes, I'd like to give it a try. But I'm wondering if there is any tutorial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use ORM here is some interesting sources:

- [DoctrineExtensions translatable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md).
- [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to integrate DoctrineExtensions in sf2.
- [TranslationFormBundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle).

Answer (score 1):

If you like to translate pages I recommend using PHPCR (http://phpcr.github.io/)

Doctrine created an ODM for it: https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm

Translation docs for PHPCR ODM: https://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/multilang.html

Example / Tutorial / More docs for Symfony CMF: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/simple_cms/multilang.html